# Segwit after downgrading bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I would like to know what will happen if I downgrade my node (currently version 25.0) to version 12.0. What are the consequences for the segwit wallet management? Are segwit transactions still relayed? Are the witnesses always saved? Can my node still start another node?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **if I downgrade my node to version 12.0. ...**

As you know, Bitcoin core v12.0 did not support Segwit.

> **Are segwit transactions still relayed?**

Nodes supporting Segwit will prune out witness data when relaying transactions to non-Segwit nodes. Those non-Segwit nodes only use the pre-Segwit network serialisation.

> **Are the witnesses always saved?**

Non-Segwit nodes do not ever see Segwit data, such as the witness data, and so do not save it.

> **Can my node still start another node?**

Consequently, non-Segwit nodes are not sufficient to start up Segwit nodes.